# ValueError: bad input shape

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, multilabel-classification

I have multilabel problem.

I was using `onevsrestclassifier` and now i want to use `onevsoneclassifier`.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifire = SVC(gamma='auto')
accuracy = []

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,random_state=None)
kf = KFold(n_splits=5)

skf.get_n_splits(X_train,y_train)

for train_index,test_index in kf.split(X_train,y_train):
    X1_train,X1_test = X_train.iloc[train_index],X_train.iloc[test_index]
    y1_train,y1_test = y_train.iloc[train_index],y_train.iloc[test_index]
    clf = OneVsOneClassifier(classifire)
#     clf = OneVsRestClassifier(classifire)
    clf.fit(X1_train,y1_train)
    prediction = clf.predict(X1_test)
    
    score = accuracy_score(prediction,y1_test)
    print(score)
```

But i am getting error only in `OneVsOneClassifier`

```
<ipython-input-47-91b351c58c24> in <module>
     11     clf = OneVsOneClassifier(classifire)
     12 #     clf = OneVsRestClassifier(classifire)
---> 13     clf.fit(X1_train,y1_train)
     14     prediction = clf.predict(X1_test)
     15 
..
ValueError: bad input shape (19051, 206)
```

I am new here. Can you help me ?

---

```
print(X1_train.shape)
print(y1_train.shape)
print(X1_test.shape)
print(y1_test.shape)
```

o/p

```
(19051, 875)
(19051, 206)
(4763, 206)
(4763, 875)
```

---

## UPDATE

```
accuracy = []

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,random_state=None)
kf = KFold(n_splits=5)

skf.get_n_splits(X_train,y_train)

for train_index,test_index in kf.split(X_train,y_train):
    X1_train,X1_test = X_train.iloc[train_index],X_train.iloc[test_index]
    y1_train,y1_test = y_train.iloc[train_index],y_train.iloc[test_index]
    clf = OneVsOneClassifier(classifire)
#     clf = OneVsRestClassifier(classifire)
    print("X1_train",X1_train.shape)
    print("y1_train",y1_train.shape)
    print('X1_test',X1_test.shape)
    print('y1_test',y1_test.shape)
    clf.fit(X1_train,y1_train)
    prediction = clf.predict(X1_test)
    
    score = accuracy_score(prediction,y1_test)
    print(score)
```

And the output is

```
X1_train (19051, 875)
y1_train (19051, 206)
X1_test (4763, 875)
y1_test (4763, 206)
```

So X1_train and test have same columns. But the error is same

Comment: the rows of X1_train and y1_train should match, before the error line type this command and print the output - print(X1_train.shape,y1_train.shape)

Comment: also print ->  
print(X_train.shape,y_train.shape)

Comment: @MadhurYadav Updated the question

Comment: X train and test should have same number of columns and (X train and Y train)  should have same number of rows and (Xtest and Ytest) should have same number of rows

Comment: your x_train and X_test doesn't have same number of columns(input features)

Comment: Vohoooo thankyou man.

Comment: @MadhurYadav Hey see this is now new ouput and we can see that it *Test and *train have same amount of colns